# Angular SPA routes on ASP.NET Web API project

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, routes, single-page-application

Created an Angular SPA with some routes on it like:

```
/messages
/messages/:id
```

With `ng serve` I can access to that pages with the URL `localhost:4200/messages` and `localhost:4200/messages/:id`

Then I built the solution and copied the generated content to an ASP.NET Web API 2 project. On the project controller, I set the default route `("/")` to return the SPA `index.html` file, so if I run the app I get the SPA with the URL: `localhost:51384`

**From the links on the page** I get to the *messages/:id* page, and the **showing URL on the browser** is:

> localhost:51384/messages/:id

[image: URL OK]

From Angular doc I know that the shown URL is local and is not sent to the server. If I try to access to that URL manually, I get an error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

[image: URL NOT OK]

That's obvious because on the WebAPI controller there is no rule for `/messages/:id`.

**I am aware that I have a concept problem**, but is there a way to access to the SPA routes with the WebAPI's URL? If not, what is the correct way to integrate a SPA into a .NET project and access to the SPA routes? Should they be accessed only through the page and not through the URL?

Thanks in advance, feel free to comment or vote positive/negative

Comment: Why not just use the `UseSpa` middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are on a good mindset for solving this.
Yes, server is trying to access `messages/12312` in its controllers, and it cannot find it.

So you have 2 solutions:

1. Changed to # way of Angular routing which doesnt require you to modify server. To do that you can see an easy setup for hash strategy here: https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles
2. This option will need you to modify your server settings and intercept all routes. Refer to this article: [ASP.Net Core + Angular 2 app /home routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105793/asp-net-core-angular-2-app-home-routing)

Comment: Solved with the hash strategy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use **HashLocationStrategy** explained here: https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles